# Creating solids of revolution with two perpendicular curves

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm quite familiar with taking one curve and creating a mesh by revolving the curve around an axis, such as through the screw modifier. This creates symmetrical cross sections . However, what if the cross sections I want are not symmetrical? How can I create a solid of revolution that follows the shape of two different, perpendicular curves? Examples below:

Top-down view. This is the lateral shape I want:

[image]

Without modifier:
[image]

Side view. I want the first curve and revolution to conform to the second curve

[image]

Without modifier:
[image]

So now, do I do some sort of deform, or something else? I thought the curve modifier might work, but my attempts resulted in something that looks like it belongs in a modern art museum. Any other techniques that might work better?

EDIT: Blend file linked below:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This isn't procedural, but ...

If the object has 2 profiles, it's not really a surface of revolution? It's an interpolation?

[image]

- Here, the 2 profiles are in planes, to make them easier to see, at right-angles to one another, intersecting at the object origin, and extruded tangentially to guide 'Blend Surface',later.
- Once done, the intersection of the planes is deleted
- And the profiles are joined with *Bridge Edge Loops*, set to 'Blend Surface', with a few cuts.
- Then the ¼ object has been *Mirror*ed in 2 axes, with 'Bisect' set to get rid of the guiding extrusions.

[image]

Comment: I'm definitely not getting intended results. Perhaps I haven't understood the instructions correctly. Or could it be that the curves have dissimilar vertices?

Comment: @hiigaran For sure, there must be the same number of vertices in the profiles. Play with the settings in the Bridge Edge Loops F9 panel, too, to get used to them.

Comment: Will do, thanks. Worst case scenario, I'll just make 0.1m intervals of circle curves as cross sections, then adjust as required. Not the most efficient solution if it does come to that, but at least there's a backup

Comment: @hiigaran I've just had a look at your file.. one of the loops is asymmetrical, so that's 3 profiles. Is that what you want?

Comment: The entire thing should be symmetrical on the Y axis, but that's it

Comment: Essentially this method, but 1. Making sure poles are coincident. 2. matching vertex counts by subdividing edges and using Loop Tools > Space to distribute verts.. Grid filling holes at poles.. some hand work.  I'm not changing the answer, because your case is very different.. https://pasteall.org/blend/65f4af5ebaaa4134b18241d57ee1d2fb